# Metrics related powershell commands in azure

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell, azure, cloud

We're trying to get the cpu percentage,disk read throughput,etc programmatically using powershell commands for metrics in azure but we are not able to get any of the commands according to new release.

Answer (score 1):

First of all are you trying to get performance details from Web/Worker Role or New preview release of Windows Azure Virtual Machines?

**With Windows Azure Virtual Machine:**

You have full access to your Azure VM and configure it the way you would do in any remote VM and the get the performance data out of it. With Windows Azure Virtual Machine if you want to get Performance data from Powershell you would need to do the following:

1. Configure to Azure VM to have PowerShell Remote Access
2. Configure Azure VM port settings so you can connect from on-premise machine (this is must and you should know that open port will open connection to VM outside)
3. Configure  Azure VM to collect performance data
4. Connect from your on-premise machine using PowerShell and collect performance data

You can find several resources on Internet to do above task.

**With Web/Worker Role:**

Even when you are using new Powershell cmdlets with Windows Azure, older commands are still accessible and working as expected. To get Performance metrics from Azure Here are some resources for your to try:

1. Windows Azure Diagnostics and PowerShell – Performance Counters:
   [Part 1](http://michaelwasham.com/2011/09/16/getting-started-with-windows-azure-powershell-cmdlets-2-0-for-diagnostics/) | [Part 2](http://michaelwasham.com/2011/09/19/windows-azure-diagnostics-and-powershell-performance-counters/)
2. [How To Easily Enable Windows Azure
   Diagnostics Remotely](http://www.davidaiken.com/2011/10/18/how-to-easily-enable-windows-azure-diagnostics-remotely/)

Comment: I am working with virtual machines and we are not using any roles. And trying it programmatically by invoking powershell commands in C#...So please provide us some suggestions and the powershell commands for the metrics...waiting 4 reply